# Trouble using a series of getlines to extract elements from user input

Tags: c++, getline

Sorry for the simple question, but I couldn't find an already available answer elsewhere.

I am building a fractional calculator that can either add, subtract, divide, or multiply two fractions(e.g 4/3 + 5/2). Firstly however, I need to parse out different elements of the user's input, like the arithmetic operator, and the numerator and denominators of the two fractions and store those elements in order to manipulate them down the line.

I thought of using a series of `getline(string)`  while altering the default delimiter to discard whitespace and / signs. However, when I try to execute my program, there seems to be issues with `getline(string)`.

Might somebody be able to point out my surely amateur mistake? The compiler isn't throwing any errors, so I'm a bit lost on what it might be.

**EDIT: I'VE SINCE BEEN ABLE TO RESOLVE THE ISSUE THANKS TO HELP. THANK YOU EVERYONE**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string numeratorfirst;
string denominatorfirst;
string arithoperator;
string numeratorsecond;
string denominatorsecond;

cout << "Enter the two fractions and the operator you want to use(IE: 3/4 + 4/6): ";
getline(cin, numeratorfirst, '/');
getline(cin, denominatorfirst, ' ');
getline(cin, arithoperator);
getline(cin, numeratorsecond, '/');
getline(cin, denominatorsecond, ' ');

cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Your fraction is: " <<  numeratorfirst << "/" << denominatorfirst << " " << arithoperator << " " << numeratorsecond << "/" << denominatorsecond << endl;


system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the issues? You might want to delineate `arithoperator` with `' '` and `denominatorsecond` with `'\n'`. I'm not sure but `arithoperator` might consume the rest of the input as it is now.

Comment: What kind of issues?

Comment: @JamesRoot  The final `cout` line which outputs to the user the fraction they've input doesn't output at all.

Comment: @JamesRoot Thank you! I was able to resolve this mistake. Thank you for helping with my noob mistake,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier using `scanf()`:

```
int numeratorfirst;
int denominatorfirst;
char arithoperator;
int numeratorsecond;
int denominatorsecond;

cout << "Enter the two fractions and the operator you want to use(IE: 3/4 + 4/6): ";

int tokens = scanf("%d/%d %c %d/%d", &numeratorfirst, &denominatorfirst,
                   &arithoperator, &numeratorsecond, &denominatorsecond);
if (tokens != 5)
    return 1;
```

This works, and it rejects invalid inputs like "foo/bar + baz/qux".

If you want a "more C++ like" solution, try this:

```
int numeratorfirst, denominatorfirst, numeratorsecond, denominatorsecond;
char slashfirst, slashsecond;
char arithoperator;

cout << "Enter the two fractions and the operator you want to use(IE: 3/4 + 4/6): ";

cin >> numeratorfirst >> slashfirst >> denominatorfirst >> arithoperator
    >> numeratorsecond >> slashsecond >> denominatorsecond;
if (!cin || slashfirst != '/' || slashsecond != '/')
    return 1;
```

Comment: Recommending type-unsafe `scanf` to a beginner is a bit heartless.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - `scanf()` is not exactly type-unsafe.  If you enable compiler warnings/errors (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror`), the compiler will stop you from using the wrong types (because it can understand the format string).  And of course everyone should enable compiler warnings/errors!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - I've added a "pure C++" example now, using `cin`.  I don't think it's any safer, but enjoy.  :)

Comment: Thanks. I wrote that the C++ example could be shortest, but thinking about it, no it will always be longer for same functionality. Hm.